# Android gradle mergeResources failed with user-mapped section opened

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've updated the tools in my project and now I use **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5'** and support libraries version **23.2.1**. The builds fails with the following error:

```
mergeVanillaDebugResources
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\jenkins\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\vanilla\debug\drawable-mdpi\my_weight.png (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
:mergeVanillaDebugResources FAILED
```

I've noticed that the name of the resource is random there.

Somebody have any idea on how to fix this or even if it is a bug?

Comment: same here with gradle:2.2.0 support library version does not matter. did you find the root cause or fix for this.

Comment: Not really. Might be related to the antivirus that was installed on that PC. Is any antivirus active on that station for you @Samuel? Maybe Windows defender?

Comment: You nailed it. It was the anti-virus' real time protection from successful compilation. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody who experience this I will answer this.
The issue seems to be related to anti-virus protection system. The solution is to disable the anti-virus or to add the whole project as an exception tot he anti-virus rules (depending on the anti-virus program)

Comment: depending on your anti virus software, you may be able to just set the build directory to a path, that the anti virus software is not checking... Like here in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868040/android-studio-set-build-directory-globally-per-machine. This may be a solution for this as well...