# Android Studio - set build directory globally (per machine)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I can set the build directory manually like following for example:

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

This can be done in my project's `build.gradle`. I want to change this directory on one computer only, so I want to somehow define this globally like I for example define credentials in the Global Properties `gradle.properties` file.

Can I somehow define the `buildDir` globally on one machine? I want to use the same project on multiple machines and without always changing the `build.gradle` file, I want to have individual build directories on each machine...

Comment: Where do you want to build ? on jenkins server or other windows system  or linux system?

Comment: on different windows machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file camed "gradle.properties" set your desired properties in it  and put it in ".gradle" folder (where your gradle is installed)

in linux ".gradle" is normally in "/home/[]your_user_name]/.gradle"

then in android view of project structure of all your project this file will appear with the name "gradle.properties (Global Properties)"

UPADATE:

if you want a global script file rather than properties file you can use init script. create a file named "init.gradle" and put it in the same directory.

your init.gradle content would be like:

```
allprojects {
buildDir = "whatever directory you want"
}
```

Comment: I have this property file(the on I meant when I was writing about credentials and global properties file) and do my global setup in there, it's a property file and no gradle file though... If I can set a build directory there, please show me how...

Comment: Thanks, that's working. Sadly it's somehow hidden, as the init file is not shown in android studio (like the global property file)

Comment: This would cause: `Duplicate content roots detected` for tests